# Keyerror, when using pandas read the .csv

Tags: python, pandas

When I preprocess the LIDC-IDLI dataset, I want to read the csv file and drop the keyword with Modality:

```
meta = pd.read_csv(metadatapath, header=None, delimiter=",", names=column_names)
meta=meta.drop(meta[meta['Modality']!='CT'].index)
meta=meta.reset_index()
```

The error is:

```
KeyError: 'Modality'
```

Why this error occurred and how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: May be your dataset does not have any column name “Modality”? Can you check again?

Comment: I check it, there is the column named "Modality".

Comment: @kkk123 could you also please paste column_names here?
meta = pd.read_csv(metadatapath, header=None, delimiter=",", names=column_names)

Comment: @Pavan Suvarna It's [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]，but if I only read by `meta=pd.read_csv(metadatapath)`, there would be another error  `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 17 fields in line 67, saw 18)`.

Comment: 'Modality' is not in column_names (I see only digits). That is why it raised the error. if you assign name = column_names then this will alter the header names. change column_names and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't the keyerror when I run the following code

```
meta = pd.read_csv(metadatapath)
meta=meta.drop(meta[meta['Modality']!='CT'].index)
meta=meta.reset_index()
```

Comment: Do you also read from the LIDC-IDLI .csv file?

Comment: I downloaded the metadata csv file from [here] (https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/LIDC-IDRI).

Comment: Thanks, it's my file's problem.